# Ubuntu 15.10 Black Screen after suspend

Tags: suspend

I just did a fresh install for ubuntu 15.10. Everything works fine except when i suspend my desktop or when i am inactive for too long the screen go off/sleep, when I try to wake it up, it shows a black screen. The display is on, i can see the display light but the screen is black. How can I fix this?

Comment: Dittos. I blame my Clevo P750dm's Nvidia card, and I don't even have the option to run integrated graphics.

Comment: I just saw the Nvidia 358 driver listed under 'additional drivers', and that seems to have solved my problem.  Finally!

Comment: @nullsteph are you using 15.10 as well? and do your pc have an onboard graphic card?

Comment: I experience this as well. As a workaround, Ctrl-Alt-F1 followed by Ctrl-Alt-F7 wakes the screen again for me.

Comment: same here http://askubuntu.com/questions/713630/ubuntu-not-starting-after-suspend/713642?noredirect=1#comment1051754_713642